# What is the difference between SAPUI5 and Fiori apps technically?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, hana-xs

There is a lot of information about SAPUI5 and SAP Fiori. What's the difference, what's needed to build them?

Answer (score 4):

**SAP Fiori is a Design Guide** for building Web-based App that are easy to use, responsive, delightful, etc.
The **technology** for SAP Fiori is based on **SAP UI5**.
A good start for information about the SAP Fiori Guidelines are open-sap courses.

To build a SAP UI5 Application and deploy it on the HANA XS Application server:

**Prerequisites**

- Eclipse
- SAP Plugins (for Eclipse Luna): from https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/luna (installed via Help -> Install New Software...
- SAP HANA (including configured XS Server)

**Build a simple SAP UI5 Application and deploy on SAP HANA XS Server:**

- In Eclipse
- Project Explorer -> Context Menu -> New -> Project... -> SAPUI5 Application Development -> Application Project -> Next -> <enter project name> -> Next -> <Enter Name> -> Finish
- Share Projrect: Right click on project -> Team -> Share Project -> SAP HANA Repository -> Next -> Choose desired Repository, choose Parent Package via Browse button
- add `.xsaccess` with content:
  { 
     "exposed" : true, 
     "authentication" : { "method" : "Form"},
     "prevent_xsrf" : true
  } and `.xsapp` (empty file) to the WebContent folder
- Change within index.html `<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"` to `<script src="/sap/ui5/1/resources/sap-ui-core.js"`
- Activate all changes: Right Click on Project -> Team -> Activate All..
- Open URL in your browser http://sap-hana-xs-url:80<instance_number>/your/parent/packages/project/WebContent/index.html (Example: http://hana:8000/tests/app01/WebContent/index.html) Be aware that the URL is case sensitive.

**Troubleshooting:**

- If you get an Error 404 then either your URL path is wrong or you might have forgotten to create and activate the `.xsapp`, `xsaccess` files
- If the page is empty then you might have forgotten to change the library path within the `index.html` file.